# AudioSource not working. Empty Exception

Tags: unity, c#, audio, file, http

I'm trying to load and play an wav file that exists in my `Application.dataPath` but when the game gets to the line `_GoAudioSource.PlayOneShot(audioLoader.audioClip);` It justs throws a empty exception and no sound is played.

I've already checked if the path is correct and it is. I've also tried uploading this wav file to an FTP and loading it via `HTTP` instead of `File:///` but nothing changes.

This is my full code:

```
     private IEnumerator WriteResponseAudio(ResponseModel res)
     {
         File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, FILENAME_RESPONSE), Convert.FromBase64String(res.intent.audio.content));
         string path = "file:///" + Application.dataPath + "/" + FILENAME_RESPONSE;
         WWW audioLoader = new WWW(path);
         yield return audioLoader;
         try
         {
             _GoAudioSource.PlayOneShot(audioLoader.audioClip);
         } catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Debug.LogError("Erro: " + ex.Message);
         }
     }
```

This is the version with HTTP request:

```
     private IEnumerator WriteResponseAudio(ResponseModel res)
     {
         File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, FILENAME_RESPONSE), Convert.FromBase64String(res.intent.audio.content));
         string path = "http://www.raphaelrosa.com/response.wav";
         WWW audioLoader = new WWW(path);
         yield return audioLoader;
         try
         {
             _GoAudioSource.PlayOneShot(audioLoader.audioClip);
         } catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Debug.LogError("Erro: " + ex.Message);
         }
     }
```

This is the console:

[image]

Comment: Note that Application.dataPath is not necessarily writable. Application.persistentDataPath should be used if you want to write files in a release version.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve my problem converting my byte array directly in a AudioClip using the code posted by Jeff Kesselman in this topic http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/737002/wav-byte-to-audioclip.html